# Msgbox alert( function() ) when click on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I would like to display a msgbox when I click on a word, for example:

```
$d = "Hello how r u";
echo "<a onclick=\"return alert('$d');\">helloo</a>";
```

It display helloo then when u click on it msgbox pops "Hello how r u".
Ps: sorry,I dont have enough reputation to display img.

Instead of just displaying a variable, can I display a Function()?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo'
<script>
 var zzz=undefined;
 function lol()
 {
  <tablestyle="width:100%">
   <tr style="background-color:#FFD700;">
    <strong>
     <th width="5%">EqID  </th>
     <th width="5%">Status</th>
     <th width="5%">Proc Lot     </th>
     <th width="5%">Moves </th>
     <th width="5%">Avl   </th>
     <th width="5%">Util  </th>
    </strong>
   </tr>
  </table>
 }
 zzz=lol();
</script>
';
echo "<a style='cursor:pointer'; onclick=\"return alert(zzz);\">helloo</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. The lol() is actually having a sample of my table header. I want the program to output the same thg like what it's happenning in the example above but the msgbox displaying my lol().

Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put HTML code in a JS function. So the following code is not correct (You cannot mix up JS code and HTML code)

```
function lol()
{
  <tablestyle="width:100%">
  <tr style="background-color:#FFD700;">
  <strong>
  <th width="5%">EqID  </th>
  <th width="5%">Status</th>
  <th width="5%">Proc Lot     </th>
  <th width="5%">Moves </th>
  <th width="5%">Avl   </th>
  <th width="5%">Util  </th>
  </strong>
  </tr>
  </table>
}
```

So this function is invalid (Grammar error).

I think you have to fix this bug before going on. Otherwise, the behavoir on the JS interpreator will be unpredictable.

A similar code is :

```
<script>
    function lol() {
       return 1;
    }
    var zzz = lol(); //// zzz = 1;
<script>

<a style='cursor:pointer'; onclick="alert(zzz);">helloo</a>  //// display message box 1
```

Comment: So there is no way i can display that table in my msgbox right?

Comment: If you want to display a HTML table in a pop-up box, alert cannot do that.

Comment: But you can use 3rd party Javascript library to "simulate" a pop-up message. For example, ExtJS, etc.

Comment: One I used was http://www.walterzorn.de/en    I wrote a small piece of code, which is what you need, I think : http://jsfiddle.net/mK9pC/3/